# Constructing random variable with given expectation

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value

Let $X$ be a random variable with support $\mathcal{X}$.
Let $1\{...\}$ be the indicator function taking value 1 if the condition inside is satisfied and 0 otherwise.

Fix $a\in \mathcal{X}$ and consider
$$
 1\Big\{\Pr(X=a)>0 \Big\}
$$
**Question**: Can we construct a **proper (non degenerate)** random variable that is a function of $X$ and $a$ (let me denote it by $f_a(X)$) such that
$$
E(f_a(X))=1\Big\{\Pr(X=a)>0 \Big\}
$$

Comment: Your definition of $f(X)$ doesn't make sense.

Comment: Once you fix the definition of $f(X)$ you can take $Y=f(X)$ for an obvious answer.

Comment: Sorry for all the nonsense in my previous question. I've edited it.

Comment: What is the meaning of $1\Big\{\Pr(X=a)>0 \Big\}$

Comment: I've written it in my question. $1\{...\}$ is the indicator function taking value 1 if the condition inside is satisfied and 0 otherwise.

Comment: In the current formulation of the question we have that $f_a(X)=1\Big\{\operatorname{Pr}(X=a)>0 \Big\}$ is an obvious answer. It is however important to note, that $1\Big\{\operatorname{Pr}(X=a)>0 \Big\}$ is not a function of $X$, so it is a bit misleading to write it as $f_a(X)$.

Comment: Thanks. You've suggested a degenerate random variable. I'm looking for a proper random variable, that is a random variable that is not a constant.